# Inquiry on dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

The following code is a bit from a bigger piece. lines is a 2D list and keyss is a 1D list. All element in lines is the same length as keyss.

```
datadict = []
for element in lines:
    for index in range(len(element)):
        datadict.append({keyss[index]: element[index]})
```

I was wondering if there was a way of writing this using dictionary comprehension? This is more of a curious question as the shown code works just fine for what I'm doing. I've been trying and couldn't find a way too. If you can could go over the syntax of how it would look a bit as well, Thanks!

EDIT#1:

Reading through the responses, I realized it wasn't really working. I'm trying to do a list comprehension where every element is a dictionary comprehension. I'm not entirely sure if that is possible or not. I want to make a list of dictionaries where I take every element in keyss and match index for index in a element in lines which is a list, if that makes sense.

EDIT #2:
I found `data_list = [{keyss[i]:row[i] for i in range(len(keyss))} for row in lines]` to work.

Comment: I think you have confused lists and dictionaries. What you call `datadict` is actually a list containing dictionaries with one key only. Is this the expected result or do you want to construct one large dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension creates a dictionary. You want a *list* comprehension:

```
datalist = [{keyss[index]:element[index]}) for element in lines
            for index in range(len(element))]
```

You can find the documentation on the syntax [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't create a dictionary, but if that was your intent, this can be accomplished by

```
dict(zip(keyss, elements))
```

or the dictionary comprehension

```
{key: value for key, value in zip(keyss, elements)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by eugene, it will be *list comprehension* and not dict comprehension. You may further simplify the code by using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as you need the from `element` and `keyss` list corresponding to same index. Hence, your simplified *list comprehension* expression should be as:

```
datalist = [{k: e} for elements in lines for e, k in zip(elements, keyss)]
```